# Java program is not getting correct value when a password is passed

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to find out the OS version of a Linux Machine, and in the argument i am passing the expected OS name, if it matches with the actual result then it will show me a message as "Correct OS , if not it will show me Wrong OS. But the problem arises when i am using a password to login for a user which is more than 10 character. If my password is less than or equals to 10 character then it works fine. If my password is exactly 10 character and i have added few more character(which is basically a wrong password). It automatically trims up to 10 character and log into the machine and executes the command.
Please let me know where my code went wrong.

```
package com.OSVerification;
import com.LogsCopy.StoreLogs;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.*;


public class LinuxOs{

private static String[] vmpass;
public static String[] getArgs() {
    return vmpass;
}
public static int main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String vmname = args[0]; // Linux machine Host name     
    String vmuid = args[1];  // user id
        String vmpass = args[2]; //password
    String osname = args[3]; // Expected OS Name
    String dbname = args[4]; // database name (used for my personal purpose)
    int check = 0;

        Session session = null;
            Channel channel = null;
 try{
  JSch jsch=new JSch();  
  jsch.removeAllIdentity();
    String command=  "uname -r | grep -o el.* | cut -d . -f1"; // command to find out the os version
        session = jsch.getSession(vmuid, vmname+".us.oracle.com", 22);
        session.setPassword(vmpass);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Host connected.");
        channel=session.openChannel("exec");
        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.connect();

  byte[] tmp=new byte[1024]; 
  String temp=null;
  while(true){ 
    while(in.available()>0){
      int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
      if(i<0)break;
       temp = new String(tmp,0,i);   
    }         

    if(channel.isClosed()){
      break;
    }
    try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
  }
String nn = temp.substring(0,6);

  if(nn.equals(osname))
  {
      check = 1;
      System.out.println("Correct OS");
  }
  else{
      System.out.println("Wrong OS");
      check =0;
      System.exit(1);
  }

  channel.disconnect();
  session.disconnect();
}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e);
}
return check;
}

}
```

Comment: Last time I checked, jsch was working fine with password >10 chars, what version are you using, are you sure the password is cut (is there a "blank" in the >10 password)?

Comment: jsch version is `0.1.31` and there is no blank space, i debugged the code, printed my password and checked, its printing the character whatever i am passing even if it is >10.

Comment: Can you try updating jsch? Latest version is 0.1.54, see http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: I tried updating the version, but of no use. Is there any alternate way of getting this done?